# Read-Only Domain Controller (RODC) in Insecure Networks - Security Benefits

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller

RODCs can be deployed in locations where physical security cannot be guaranteed, to improve the security. This is the primary use case where a RODC should be deployed.

An other scenario would be to deploy a RODC in an insecure network segment (e.g. where client systems resides), disable or not allow credential caching on the RODC and block connections from the clients to RW Domain Controllers. Obviously a connection between the RODC and a RW Domain Controller must be allowed.

Now my question for this scenario: what are the security benefits here? E.g. if the RODC gets compromised, credentials cannot be dumped or used for Pass-the-Hash attacks but RODC can be abused as jumphost to RW Domain Controllers if a high privileged users gets compromised?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question seems to be simple. You should disable password replication this way no credentials will be cached on the RODC. RODC will make a call to RDWC any time user requires authentication.

As for the admins, they should not be allowed to login on RODC. You have the capability to create RODC admins without granting them any RDWC rights. So those two should be kept separate.